# Powershell Strip all directory paths from file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

OK what I am trying to do is make a script that will read each line of a text file, "directory.txt" and export every line that is to a file and not to a directory. Example below.

> I'm just trying to remove the paths to directories like "C:\users\"
>   and keep any path that is to a file like "C:\users\file.txt"

In the test file, Direcory.txt" there will be the following:

> C:\path\path\folder\
>   C:\path\path\file.ext
>   C:\path\path\path\path\folder

The script will need to read the text file above and export the following line to a new text file.

> C:\path\path\file.ext

The batch script equivalent would be the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A IN (directory.txt) DO CALL:NoDir "%%A"
pause
EXIT /B

:NoDir
IF "%~x1" NEQ "" ECHO %~1>>nodir.txt
EXIT /B
```

Batch script can't handle a file of 400mb so need to use powershell to do it o.0

Answer (score 1):

FTR: The condition `if "%~x1" neq ""` does not do what you seem to expect. It will match not only folders, but also files without an extension.

Anyway, in PowerShell you'd probably do something like this to list only items that are not directories:

```
Get-Content \PATH\TO\directory.txt `
  | Get-Item `
  | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } `
  | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Actually it does exactly what I intended, it will only echo files with an extension and will ignore directories. Just tested to verify.

Comment: It will not output something like `C:\path\file_without_ext`. If that's what you want, you'll have to change the `Where-Object` condition from `-not $_.PSIsContainer` to `$_.Extension -ne ""`.

Comment: thats not what i wanted im just trying to remove the paths to directories like "C:\users\" and keep any path that is to a file like "C:\users\file.txt"

Comment: Then, like I said before, `"%~x1" neq ""` will **not** do what you want, because it will also exclude **files with no extension**. My original suggestion will do what you want for files/folders that exist on the computer. If you want to test for non-existing paths there is no way to distinguish between a folder and a file without extension. In that case your best bet is most likely something like this: `Get-Content \PATH\TO\directory.txt | where { $_ -match "\.[^\\]*$" }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question (batch example shows all paths), maybe that's what you're looking for:

```
Get-Content directory.txt | Where-Object {$_ -eq 'C:\path\path\file.ext'}
```

Comment: Sorry edited the first post, to show what the script is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether you're concerned if they are valid paths or not. The following outputs to the host the lines that are either valid files (using the '-PathType leaf' parameter of the Test-Path cmdlet), or if the last 4 characters of the last item in the path are a dot followed by 3 letters.

```
$Lines = Get-Content C:\Path\to\file.txt

foreach ( $line in $Lines )
{
  if ( (Test-Path $line -PathType leaf) -OR ($line -match "\.\w{3}$") )
  {
    Write-Host $line
  }
}
```

If you find your file extensions are longer than 3 letters, you can change the regex appropriately (`"\.\w{3,4}$"` for 4 character extensions, or `"\.[\w\d]{3,4}$` to match extensions that are 3 or 4 characters long and might include numbers)

And the one-liner:

```
Get-Content C:\Path\to\file.txt | % { if ((Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) -OR ($_ -match "\.\w{3}$")) { $_ } }
```